# counting key value in map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Let the map be : `map <string , int>`
Now I want to insert the string and if the same string is inserted again , store the count in the integer part.
Show me a way??

Comment: You can't insert the same key twice. Maybe you need `m["string"]++;`?

Comment: "Show me a way??" No. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
++m.insert(std::make_pair("Hello", 0)).first->second;
```

Or more easily:

```
++m["hello"];
```

The first approach allows you to tell whether or not the string already existed if you store the result of the `insert` operation, e.g. `auto p = m.insert(...); ++p.first->second;` — then `p.second` tells you whether the insert operation succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with the following code : `my_map[key]++;`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe just `m["key"]++` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Since `int{}` is `0`, you just need:

```
++m[str];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the find() method to check if the key is in the mapping.

```
std::map<string, int> mapping;
std::string str;
//...

if(mapping.find(str) != mapping.end()) {
    mapping[str]++;
} else {
    mapping[str] = 1;
}
```

Comment: No need for the if-else block. Just `mapping[str]++` will do.

Comment: Unless the initial value must be something else than 1.